# interchanging of sup and inf in an optimization problem

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose we have
$$g(\mathbf{y}) = \sup_{\mathbf{x}\in \text{dom} f} \{\inf_{\mathbf{C} \in {\text{S}}}  \{\mathbf{y}^T \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{C} \mathbf{\mathbf{x}}\}\} $$

where $\text{S} \subset\mathbb{S}_{++}^n$ ($S$ a compact convex subset of positive definite matrices). 
Could we interchange the $\sup$ and $\inf$ in this optimization problem like below:

$$g(\mathbf{y}) = \inf_{\mathbf{C} \in {\text{S}}} \{\sup_{\mathbf{x}\in \text{dom} f}  \{\mathbf{y}^T \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{C} \mathbf{\mathbf{x}}\}\}\qquad *?*$$

---

Also, what is the **general condition** for this interchange its order? I mean under what conditions we have:
$$\sup_{\mathbf{x}\in X} \{\inf_{\mathbf{C} \in {\text{S}}}  \{f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{C})\}\} = \inf_{\mathbf{C} \in {\text{S}}} \{\sup_{\mathbf{x}\in X}  \{f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{C})\}\}.$$

Comment: Have you seen Sion's minimax theorem?

Comment: Also, in general, $\sup_x \inf_y f(x,y) \le \inf_y \sup_x f(x,y)$

Comment: @David: I mean when just equality holds?

Comment: The only general statement that I know about that is sions mininax theorem. Perhaps there are others?

Comment: isn't the infimum $\inf_{C\in S} y^Tx - x^TCx$ always equal to $-\infty$? As long as $\operatorname{dom} f$ contains something other than $0$, we can just choose $C=NI$ for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and the function becomes $y^Tx-N\|x\|_2^2$ which goes to $-\infty$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: @amakelov: the function is defined such that it cannot have infinite value; I mean the set $S$ is bounded.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Then what's wrong with using von Neumann's minimax theorem?

Comment: No problem @amakelov. I need to get sure about using von Neumann's minimax theorem; also if there would be other theorems or possibilities. Thanks for your notice.

Comment: @amakelov: But based on the von Neumann's minimax theorem, in above problem, the $\sup$ and $\inf$ cannot be interchanged! Isn't it?

Comment: Lookup Sion's minimax theorem.